# How to add back button to custom toolbar layout on AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, toolbar, appcompatactivity

I'm developing an android app. I'm using AppCompatActivity and would like to add back button to my custom toolbar. Here is the code of the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="54dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:src="@drawable/logo" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="24px"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="9dip"
           android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
           android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
           android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my activity code:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmarks);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);

    //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(R.string.bookmarks);
```

What do I have to add that the back button will be displayed?

Best,
B.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity just add this code:

```
mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_tool_bar_id);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
    Drawable upArrow = ResUtils.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material, null);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(ResUtils.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryLightText), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

You can change the color of your back button

Comment: Tnx, but this doesn't work ... Hmmm
I updated the original post with the activity code

Comment: Try to make it a toolbar and pass it as an arguement to setSupportActionBar(mToolBar); method

Comment: the layout does not contain a toolbar, so its not possible to use your findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your layout (activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

in onCreate method add this code:

```
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Drawable drawable= ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(this.getResources(), R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material, null);

    //custom color
    //drawable.setColorFilter(ResourcesCompat.getColor(this.getResources(), R.color.colorPrimaryLightText, null), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```

change your root layout to LinearLayout

Comment: Please update this to include a small description of what it achieves to help the user understand.